# How to map extra additional property on Entity database call

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have the following class:

```
public class MessageThread
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Messages can relate to messages through replies
    /// </summary>
    public virtual List<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int CountUnreadMessages {get;set;}
}
```

In my repository I get a list of MessageThread back like so:

```
return this.PrepareAllMessageThreadsQuery( page, amount, sort, order, searchCriteria )
    .Where(x => x.SentTo.Id == userID)
    .Skip((page - 1) * amount)
    .Take(amount);
```

I would like to fill up the CountUnreadMessages part aswell... how do I go about doing this... I assume it looks something like this:

```
return this.PrepareAllMessageThreadsQuery( page, amount, sort, order, searchCriteria )
    .Where(x => x.SentTo.Id == userID)
    .Select(x => {
        x.UnreadMessageCount = x.Messages.Where(a => a.Read == false).Count();
    })        
    .Skip((page - 1) * amount)
    .Take(amount);
```

Obviously the above doesn't work :)

How do I go about doing this?

I realise there might be an options like this (although I can't get it to work):

```
return this.PrepareAllMessageThreadsQuery( page, amount, sort, order, searchCriteria )
    .Where(x => x.SentTo.Id == userID)
    .Select(x => new MessageThread() {
        // Lots of other properties have to be mapped too :(
        UnreadMessageCount = x.Messages.Where(a => a.Read == false).Count()
    })        
    .Skip((page - 1) * amount)
    .Take(amount);
```

But I have to remap an entire class just for the sake of it...

**EDIT......**

I've gone for this:

```
public class MessageThread
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Messages can relate to messages through replies
    /// </summary>
    public virtual IList<Message> Messages { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public int UnreadMessageCount
    {
        get
        {
            if( this.Messages == null )
            {
                return 0;
            }

            return this.Messages.Where(x => x.Read == false).Count();
        }
    }
}
```

**Does this now look okay?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `UnreadMessageCount` a get-only property. This will only work when `Messages` is loaded with your objects.

```
[NotMapped]
public int CountUnreadMessages 
{
    get
    {
        return Messages.Count(x => !x.Read);
    }
}
```

Comment: Won't it fetch all messages belonging to a thread (which could be thousands) before tying to then get a count? Or does the virtual Messages  property not work like that... Should I convert it from a List<Message> to an Enumerable so that the property does not make the db call yet?

Comment: if you want this only for a specific query then you should just do `Select( x=> new Mytype { CountUnreadMessages  = x.Messages.Count(x => !x.Read) })`, if this is something you'll use all the time, and the `Messages` property will regularly be populated, then this will run in memory.

Comment: I'm not sure how your `PrepareAllMessageThreadsQuery` works, it kind of depends on that to determine whether or not this needs to hit the database.

Comment: Hm, I've changed the Messages property to IEnumerable to delay the query of messages so that I don't just wastefully get ALL messages and then do a count at the end... Does that sound correct?

Comment: PrepareAllMessageThreadsQuery returns an IQueryable. I've added to OP